# Create xsd.Element with attribute and string value using Zeep

Tags: python, python-3.x, zeep

I'm trying to create a custom SOAP header element using Zeep which has both an attribute and a string value. No other child elements. I'm sure I'm missing out on some piece of information on how to make it, and hope someone can point me in the right direction.

What I want is the following:

```xml
<wsse:Password Type="StringAttribute">StringPasswordValue</wsse:Password>
```

What I've tried so far (and I'm just guessing at syntaxes here):

```py
password_header = xsd.Element('{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Password', xsd.ComplexType([
    xsd.String(),
    xsd.Attribute('Type', xsd.String())
    ]))

password_value = password_header('StringPasswordValue', Type='StringAttribute')
```

I was also perhaps expecting it to be doable without a `xsd.ComplexType`, just specifying attributes to a `xsd.String`, but no such luck. I do not want to make this by using a `wsse:UsernameToken`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the password element by using the `zeep.wsse.utils` module:

```
from zeep.wsse.utils import WSSE
password = WSSE.Password("StringPasswordValue", Type="StringAttribute")
```

This is based on [how the password is created for UsernameToken](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/blob/4e16b7726b5027e83d0dbe911bd45f153b7a09dc/src/zeep/wsse/username.py#L97).

Or you can create the element using `lxml` directly (just as [zeep does it](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/blob/4e16b7726b5027e83d0dbe911bd45f153b7a09dc/src/zeep/wsse/utils.py#L12)).

```
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker

wsse_ns = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
builder = ElementMaker(namespace=wsse_ns, nsmap={"wsse": wsse_ns})
password = builder.Password("StringPasswordValue", Type="StringAttribute")
```